# Convert epoch to days

Tags: php, date

I have the following code:

```
<?php
function cuantosdias($d){
    $d = strtotime($d);
    $c = strtotime("now");
    $e = $c - $d;
    return $e;
};
$fecha = "13-10-2016 00:00:00";
$cant = cuantosdias($fecha);
echo $cant/86400 . "\n";
```

I get the days between 2 dates.

I wonder how can I get $cant in format:d H:i:s.

Is there a function to do that?

Comment: Use [DateTime objects](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) and the [diff()](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php) method, which gives you a [DateInterval object](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php) which you can format the difference using the [format()](http://php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php) method

Comment: Why did you downvote? Could you explain, so I can learn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply, you can try this way:

```
<?php

$fecha = "13-10-2016 00:00:00";

function dateDifference($date, $differenceFormat = '%y year(s) %m month(s) %d day(s) %H:%i:%s' )
{
    $datetime1 = date_create($date);
    $datetime2 = date_create();
    $interval = date_diff($datetime1, $datetime2);

    return $interval->format($differenceFormat);

}

echo dateDifference($fecha);
```